# Are Rails create table migrations supposed to have created_at and updated_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-migrations

In my experience, `Rails g migration` create table migrations always added timestamps to the table. But that is not happening:

```
rails g migration CreateFoo bar:references

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.references :bar, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

Is this expected behavior? Did this change in Rails 4?

ActiveRecord 4.1.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

timestamps are only created with generating models.

here's an example from the guide.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

```
$ bin/rails generate migration CreateProducts name:string part_number:string
```

generates

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :part_number
    end
  end
end
```

**up**

You can make a suggestion by looking at provided code examples there.

Also look at:

```
rails g migration --help
rails g model --help
```

and you will see that timestamps are only provided automatically with "g model" (and you can actually disable it for models)

Comment: Does the guide state that timestamps are only included when generating models?

Answer (score 1):

Use Rails generate model function to create model, migration and test/spec:

`rails g model CreateFoo bar:references`

This will add the `t.timestamps` in your migration.